# SetDoc in Firebase

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

```
useEffect(() => {
    const setCount = async () => {
        try {
            await setDoc(db, "data", "data", {
                test: { choice }
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    };
    setCount();
}, []);
```

I used the above code to try to write a user input into a document. It's a brand new setup fireStore. And I got e.message as below:

expected type 'va', but it was: a custom Ba object

Anyone could help me sort this out? thanks!

Comment: It seems like your `choice` variable is not one of the [supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) of Firestore. If that doesn't explain, can you show how `choice` is initialized.

Comment: const［choice, setChoice] =useState("").    Yet, I replaced {choice}  with "hi", the issue persists. Please kindly advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to pass `db` (Firestore instance)  to `setDoc`. You pass `doc` (a document).

Like below:

```
import { doc } from "firebase/firestore"; // import this if you have not.

useEffect(() => {
  const setCount = async () => {
    try {
      await setDoc(doc(db, "data", "data"), { // passing doc here
        test: { choice }
      });
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  };
  setCount();
}, []);
```